# Change ubuntu on ubuntu base distro without loose any config

Tags: upgrade, configuration

Is this possible? 
Do fresh install ubuntu based or ubuntu itself and copy from old machine all configuration. Not only user conf(that's easy), but also, all system configuration include ssh keys for remote servers ( really annoing config that each time), DB from mysql and etc.. 
Like system was only updated not, fresh installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. No, because in general switching the base distribution can influence many things -- for example, the distributions might have different versions of certain packages, and consequently use different, incompatible configuration files for certain services. There is hardly a way of doing it automatically.

Yes, because you can always find out what exactly it is that you have to configure each time and try to deal with it in a semi-manual way. For example, I'm not sure what you mean by "ssh keys for remote servers" -- I keep them in ~/.ssh/, so why should that change when the server is reinstalled?

For several files, you can create a stable directory on, say, your home partition, where you will keep the config files (like hosts or whatever), and link them to your `/etc` directory or another appropriate place.

There are also specialized systems to deal with propagating configuration settings -- see for example [puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29).